# How to access ajax variable in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to pass the *ajax* variable to *php* page.

Here I am alerting the value, and it is showing the value. But when I send the value to *php* page, it is not getting the value and performing delete operation.

Here is what I have tried,

**ajax code:**

```
function remove() 
{
    if(a=="") 
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
       if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
       {
           document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","theaterdel.php?q="+a,true);
    alert(a)
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**php code:**

```
<?php
$q = strtolower(trim($_GET["q"]));
try 
{
   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
   echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$sql = 'DELETE  FROM theater WHERE LOWER(address) = :q';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':q', $q);
$sth->execute();
$dbh = null;
?>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you `echo $_GET["q"]`

Comment: What's in the response? (check [network tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network?hl=nl#http_response) in the developer tools) and what's the response if you replace your php code with @Shadowfax echo statement.

Comment: @Shadowfax yes i tried using echo $_GET["q"], but it is not showing the result

Answer (score 0):

You are using AJAX to send HTTP GET request, and sending "q" as a parameter with a value you generated in your JavaScript.

its same like someone executes this url http://:/my-app?q=the%20value

So, by the time this request reaches your PHP, you should be able to handle Get requests and Get parameters as you always do, no difference. Also while sending value from JavaScript, via AJAX, try to encode your URI values so that they are sent properly escaped in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `var_dump($_GET["q"]);` in your PHP file.
Whatever it produces it should appear in your `#txtHint` element (at least you should get `null`.
If you don't get anything, than you probably got the path to your PHP file wrong, so try with absolute URL just to see if it works.